# Embed user action after processing every character in Ragel

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine, ragel

I'm using Ragel to evaluate FSAs, and I need to have a segment of code run after every evaluation of a character in the input. Ragel has operators that allow user actions to be embedded on transitions and states; however, after some testing it seems that these user actions are only run the first time the machine enters a given state. Thus, if the machine stays in one state across several characters, no user actions will be run. Is there a method of having a user action run every time ragel processes an input character?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "All Transition Action" (3.1.3 section of the manual) is what you need.

```
main := (your machine) $YourAction;
```

For example

```
main := (any* ('foo'|'bar') any*) ${printf ("char: %c\n", *p);};
```